# Surprising result for derivative

Tags: calculus

I need to calculate the derivative of the following function:

$f(x)=x^{10-6 \sqrt{x}}$

My logic goes like this: we can use the chain rule, where the "inner function" is $10-6 \sqrt{x}$, and the "outer function" is the power function. So the result should be the derivative of the outer function

$(10-6 \sqrt{x})  x^{9-6 \sqrt{x}}$

multiplied by the derivative of the inner function

$-3 \over \sqrt{x}$

However, it seems that this result is wrong. If I calculate it with the program *Mathematica*, it gives the result

$x^{10-6 \sqrt{x}} ({10-6 \sqrt{x} \over x} - {3 ln x \over \sqrt x})$

which completely surprises me. What is this? Where is a logarithm coming from? So I have the right answer, but I don't understand what steps lead to this solution.

Comment: What is "the power function"? Note that $f(x) = e^{g(x)\cdot\ln(x)}$, where $g(x) = 10-6\sqrt x$.

Comment: [Logarithmic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation) could also be of use.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp The power function is $f(x) = x^p$, where p is the power... Why is this not good as an outer function for a chain rule?

Comment: @WannaKnow Because $p$ is a function of $x$ when it must be a constant.

Comment: OK, I understand it now, thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness and assuming you've probably made some progress by now, $$f(x)=x^{10-6\sqrt{x}}\implies \ln(f(x))=\ln\Bigl(x^{10-6\sqrt{x}}\Bigr)=\left(10-6\sqrt{x}\right)\ln(x)$$ $$\implies\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln(f(x))\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\left(10-6\sqrt{x}\right)\ln(x)\right)\implies\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=(10-6\sqrt{x})\cdot\frac{1}{x}+\left(-6\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)\ln(x)\implies f'(x)=f(x)\cdot\left[(10-6\sqrt{x})\cdot\frac{1}{x}+\left(-6\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)\ln(x)\right]$$ $$=x^{10-6\sqrt{x}}\left[(10-6\sqrt{x})\cdot\frac{1}{x}+\left(\dfrac{-3}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\ln(x)\right]$$
and you can simplify if you want.